# Calculate the Mean of the Row in a Data Frame excluding 0 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to calculate the mean of the data points between two specific columns within a data frame.

Attached is the code

```
library(tidyverse)

Book7 <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X- X/X/Book7.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet12")

Start_Date <- tail(head(colnames(Book7),3),1)
End_Date <- tail(colnames(Book7),1)

Book7 <- head(Book7,2) 

Book7 <- Book7 %>% 
  mutate(Average =  rowMeans(pick(any_of(Start_Date):any_of(End_Date)),na.rm = T))
```

The issue I am facing is that, even though the code is working and `na.rm=True` , the average includes 0 values. What do I do to ensure that the 0 are not included in the calculation of Mean within the above mentioned code.

The data set I am working with is given below:

```
structure(list(Material = c("XAB-01-02-03", "XAB-01-02-03"), 
    `Calendar Year/Week` = c("Deal", "Profit"), `2023/28` = c(6, 
    4), `2023/29` = c(92, 92), `2023/30` = c(81, 56), `2023/31` = c(5, 
    0), `2023/32` = c(54, 41), `2023/33` = c(82, 73), `2023/34` = c(30, 
    40), `2023/35` = c(46, 1), `2023/36` = c(4, 43), `2023/37` = c(83, 
    73), `2023/38` = c(78, 75), `2023/39` = c(85, 18), `2023/40` = c(60, 
    38), `2023/41` = c(51, 61), `2023/42` = c(65, 94), `2023/43` = c(74, 
    65), `2023/44` = c(12, 20), `2023/45` = c(1, 65)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The average which I get for the second row is 47 but when the 0 is excluded this should be 50.52.

Can someone help me out here to find the right way to do this with this code. ?

Attached is the expected output:

[image]

Comment: You could use `apply` to apply a function rowwise and `mean(x[x!=0])`.  Alternatively, you could replace all the 0s with NA (assuming that's acceptable for your downstream work) and just rely on the `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: In fact a brief search shows these exact examples in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63306620/16730940

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating rowMean ignoring 0 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306620/calculating-rowmean-ignoring-0-values)

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen The issue is I dont want to replace all the 0 in the data frame with NA just the once which are present within the range. So I cant get that code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what our friends have suggested in the comments, we can change everything in the data frame which is 0 to NA and perform the function and then change back the NA to 0, Try using this.

```
Book7 <- Book7 %>% 
  #Replace everything which is 0 in the data frame to NA
  replace(.,Book7==0,NA) %>% 
  #Now the na.rm = True would work as 0 are replaced by NA
  mutate(Average = rowMeans(pick(any_of(Start_Date):any_of(End_Date)),na.rm = T)) %>%
  #And we change the NA back to 0 and you data set is back to normal
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.